# Address of &this instantiated class?

Tags: c++

My goal is to write a function that returns the address of the instantiated class from which it is called.

My initial guess was

return &this

But this does not yield any good results.

Any and all suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply `return this` will return the address of an object from within that object.

Comment: Haha, couldn't be easier! Thanks! I guess I thought that that would return the instantiated class by copy, but that clearly doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suppose you already thought of this, but you do `this->function()` so `this` representing a pointer makes sense

Answer (score 1):

this is a pointer. You don't want the address of the this pointer, you want this itself.

Note that under virtual inheritance (virtual base classes, multiple inheritance), the this pointer may not be the same at all times (it would depend on where in the inheritance-graph it is pointing at the specific point in time).

Well defined conversions do exist (dynamic_cast) so no unsolvable problems there, just saying that you should not blindly believe that

```
MultiplyDerived* d = &someInstance;
Base* b = d;

bool test = ((void*) b) == ((void*) d);
```

`test` need not always be true (I think it is even compiler-dependent, i.e. implementation specific what happens when).

Comment: `this` does not even have an address, it's an rvalue.

Comment: @Fred: Yeah, I guess that's sort of what I was looking for to put in words. I'm just happy I didn't actually say that `this` was an address :) (though, in practice, I don't know any compiler in which it isn't at least some sort of raw address under the covers; Now for `member-function-pointers`... That's a similar story: this isn't an adress, _and_ it is usually not implemented as such either.